# How perform Kinetic energy summation in matlab, between matrixs and vector

Tags: matlab, physics, energy

[image: Formula]

```
%% Popolazione di detriti

% Costanti
Mv=10000; % 10000 kg massa nominale velivolo
V_0 = 200*.3048; % velocità al distacco dalla WKT in m/s a 14325 m

N=1000
D=rand(N,1); % vettore debris di 100 numeri casuali tra 0 e 1
somma=sum(D); 
m_i=(D/somma)*Mv; %mass casuale dei detriti
ver=sum(m_i); % verifica che la somma dei dei 100 pezzi razionalizzati restituisce il peso del velivolo

vx_i = randn(N,1); % componenti random di velocità nelle tre direzioni
vy_i = randn(N,1); 
vz_i= randn(N,1);
DeltaV_iStar= [vx_i,vy_i,vz_i]; % matrix velocity i-esima debris
    %% Momentum
DeltaQ_err=zeros(1,3);
DeltaQ=zeros(N,3); %inizializzo matrice 
for k=1:N
    DeltaQ(k,:)=(m_i(k)*DeltaV_iStar(k,:));  
    DeltaQ_err=DeltaQ_err+DeltaQ(k,:);
end
DeltaQ_err


DeltaV_err = DeltaQ_err/Mv ; % errore da togliere agli incrementi iniziali
DeltaV_c = DeltaV_iStar-DeltaV_err;

DeltaQ_err2=zeros(1,3);
DeltaQ=zeros(N,3); %inizializzo matrice 
for k=1:N
  DeltaQ(k,:)=(m_i(k)*DeltaV_c(k,:));  
  DeltaQ_err2=DeltaQ_err2+DeltaQ(k,:);
end
DeltaQ_err2


%% Kinetic Energy
V_element= randn(3,1); % componenti della velocità iniziale
B = V_element/norm(V_element) 
v=V_0*B
vlength= norm(v);

prodotto=0;
Ek_d=0;
for k=1:N 
    prodotto(k,:)=.5*[m_i(k)*(v(k)+DeltaV_c(k,:)).^2];
    Ek_d=Ek_d+prodotto(k,:);
end
Ek_d
```

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is
> 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-3.
>
> Error in Debris_Footprint (line 59)
> prodotto(k,:)=.5*[m_i(k)*(v(k)+DeltaV_c(k,:)).^2];

I tried with a for loop but the result I get is a vector. the problem is that kinetic energy **is NOT** **a vector quantity**.
In my code: m is **m_i**  V0 = **v** DeltaVc = **DeltaV_c**.
I upload the entire code for a better understanding.
It's for a university project. The first part of the code is right according to my pofessor. I need help with the **kinetic energy** part

Comment: How would you do that with a pen and paper ? What did you try ? And what result do you get ? I tired X is not an answer, you need to paste the code here.

Comment: There's a function called `sum` in matlab.

Comment: But with  'sum'  I can't index 'k=1:N'

Comment: Update: I have updated the code with what I have done, but it is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the total kinetic energy of a body is the sum of its kinetic energy in each direction, so we just loop over the 3 directions and get the kinetic energy in each direction and sum them for each particle.

```matlab
prodotto=0;
Ek_d=0;
for k=1:N
    for direction = 1:3
    prodotto = .5*m_i(k)*(v(direction)+DeltaV_c(k,direction)).^2;
    Ek_d=Ek_d+prodotto;
    end
end
Ek_d
```

this can be written more efficiently, but this form best explains the operation.

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do  and what is m and v0 and delta vc.

let's say m is matrix and v is velocity matrix.
write like this :

```matlab
sum =0;
for i=1:N
   sum = (1/2)* m.*((v+vc).*(v+vc))+sum;
end
```

in this way you can get final sum value.

Comment: please let me know the clear picture, if your doubt is not clear. avctually what you want to do?